# Specifying a frame icon on Scala’s Swing Frame

Tags: swing, scala, icons, nimbus

How can you set a new frame icon on Scala’s `scala.swing.Frame` class? What are the intentions behind `Frame.iconImage: Image` and `Frame.iconify()`? I can’t figure out, what they’re doing.

Here’s my last attempt

```
import scala.swing.Frame

class MyFrame extends Frame {
  iconImage = toolkit.getImage("src/main/resources/icon.png")
  visible = true
}
```

I also tried several other methods, but nothing worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing you are on OS X. Sadly, the icon decoration does not work for the OS X look and feel, neither does it work for Nimbus look and feel which seems to not come with a specific window decoration (uses title bar from OS X).

So you will need a look and feel that does paint its own window title bar:

```
import scala.swing._
import javax.swing._
UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel)
JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true)

val f = new Frame {
   iconImage = toolkit.getImage(new java.net.URL(
      "http://www.scala-lang.org/sites/default/files/favicon.gif"))
   size = new Dimension(200, 200)
   visible = true
}
```

The only chance with OS X window title bars is if you want to decorate with the default icon used for a particular file.

Look for `Window.documentFile` here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#technotes/tn2007/tn2196.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS10004439

Comment: “[…] neither does it work for Nimbus look and feel […]”. That’s it. I am using Nimbus, but didn’t mention that here.

Comment: cf. http://bugs.sun.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do;jsessionid=a655306f41e2c17d50e0bf54ea6?bug_id=6675399 -- don't know if they did anything about it in Java 7 (I'm stuck to Java 6 Apple)

Comment: No they didn’t. I’m using Java 7.

Answer (score 1):

What you have there should work, but if the getImage can't find the file, it fails silently.
Since you have a relative path, it's probably because you code isn't executing in the directory you intended.

On Ubuntu this should highlight the difference. I get one window with a smiley icon and one with the standard java icon.

```
new Frame() {
  iconImage = toolkit.getImage("/usr/share/icons/gnome/16x16/emotes/stock_smiley-10.png")
  size = new Dimension(200, 200)
  visible = true
}
new Frame() {
  iconImage = toolkit.getImage("xxx")
  size = new Dimension(200, 200)
  visible = true
}
```