# Set Application Icon in Scala Swing

Tags: swing, scala

I am trying to set the application icon for a simple scala swing application.  I set the `MainFrame.iconImage` but that seems to have no effect.  The application's icon in the windows taskbar and the window frame is still the java logo.

Here is the test code I am using.

```
package uiTest

import swing._
import swing.event._
import Swing._
import javax.swing._

object HelloWorld extends SimpleSwingApplication {

  def top = new MainFrame {

    title = "Hello World"
    preferredSize = new Dimension(200, 200)

    iconImage = toolkit.getImage("/Logo.png") // does nothing.
    println(iconImage.getWidth(peer)) // -1

    contents = new BoxPanel(Orientation.Vertical) {
      contents += new Label {
        // successfully displays my logo so no resource issues.
        icon = new ImageIcon(getClass.getResource("/Logo.png"))
      }
    }
  }
}
```

My only idea left is that `Frame.iconImage` has nothing to do with the application icon.  In that case, where do I set the application icon? An then what does `Frame.iconImage` do then?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11308277/specifying-a-frame-icon-on-scala-s-swing-frame) indicated that it was not possbile on OSX.  Is that the same on Windows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the code that works you're using `getResource`, indicating that the file is located in your resource directory, but when you try to set the icon, you're using the path "/Logo.png" directly, indicating that it's located in the root directory.

Comment: Ahh, I assumed `toolkit.getImage` worked from the resource directory by default for some reason.